# Node.js javascript modules on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a game using node.js+express+socket.io. It took a long time to get where I am but i feel it finally got me.
I have server which servs html and js files in this way:

```
app.post('/game', function(req, res) {
     handleGame(req, res); //it opens file using fs and forwards with res.end(readFile);
});

app.get('/scripts/*', function(req, res) {
     handleStatic(req, res); //same schema
});
```

And now, I'm logged and on site [game.html](http://pastebin.com/uXwgbRwc) (received from first app.post).
It loaded fine, initRight is changed to 'bbbb', If I open 'source code' in firefox, I can click and see both [player.js](http://pastebin.com/QmNhYPUC) and [game.js](http://pastebin.com/x71UyeJd) source code. Hovewer, inside init() function of game.js module, there should be change to initRight field again to 'AAAAA', but as I can see Player function from player module is invisible inside game module (I've detected that when I was moving socket.io handlers to different module). I'm doing that in this way because I've seen it in different project and I really don't want next overwhelm with putting some require.js to get require() function etc. My question is should it work? If yes why it might not here?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking. I suggest you show code that is relevant to the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is confusing and I don't see the connection with NodeJS for your question, the problem is that your JavaScript has mutliple issues.

I copied your code to JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/iqudic/4/edit  (and live: http://jsbin.com/iqudic/4)

Then, I cleaned it up a little bit.

You likely would want to put the associated attributes on the instance of the Player object rather than returning them as a new object like you were.

```
var Player = function(playerNick, playerId, playerSocket) {
  this.nick = playerNick;
  this.id = playerId;
  this.socket = playerSocket;
};
```

Secondly, and this was causing the `AAAAAA` to not appear:

```
function init() {
    // socket and socket.id should be defined before creating the Player
    localPlayer = new Player('AAAAAA', socket.id, socket);
    document.getElementById('initRight').innerHTML = localPlayer.nick;
}
```

Your code assumes that there is a `socket.id` and `socket` object available within the `init` function. It's crashing on that line. You should always take a look at the Console window of your favorite web browser.

[image: socket is not defined]

Comment: thank you WiredPrairie, with your response you've solved 2 of my problems ;)